# popup menu for icon in recyclerView that is populted with json data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i've created a recyclerview with 2 textViews and an imageView. i've also populated the recyclerView with JSON data. what i want to acheive is that when i click on the imageView i should get a popup menu and on clicking on the popup menu perform certain operations.

the code that i used is as follows 
recyclerAdapter.java

```
 private List<FeedItem> feedItemList;
private Context mContext;

public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<FeedItem> feedItemList) {
    this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_adapter, null);

    CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, int i) {
    FeedItem feedItem = feedItemList.get(i);
    //Setting text view title
    customViewHolder.textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getHehw()));
    customViewHolder.textView1.setText(Html.fromHtml(feedItem.getHesub()));
    customViewHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(clickListener);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != feedItemList ? feedItemList.size() : 0);
}

public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView textView,textView1;
    protected ImageView imageView;
    public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        this.imageView= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        this.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.HeHw);
        this.textView1= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.HeSub);
    }
}
View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        CustomViewHolder holder = (CustomViewHolder) view.getTag();
        int position = holder.getPosition();

        FeedItem feedItem = feedItemList.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(mContext, feedItem.getThumbnail(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
};
```

MainActivity.java

```
ItemClickSupport.addTo(mRecyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
                    // retreives the specified value from the recyclerView
                    try {
                        String iID = posts.getJSONObject(position).getString("SERIAL_NUMBER");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), iID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: So what's the problem you're facing?

Comment: i've an image view inside the recyclerView. when i click on it i need to get a popup menu